# Need an example using dht_put_item with libtorrent

Tags: c++, dht, libtorrent

I'm trying to use dht to keep mutable data with libtorrent. As far as I can understand, the right way is to use the method dht_put_item from session. The problem is that I need to pass a callback function and I don't know what I'm doing wrong... my code looks like the following

```
namespace lt = libtorrent;

//The callback function
void cb(lt::entry& cdentry, boost::array<char,64>& cbarray, boost::uint64_t& cbint, std::string const& cbstring){
    //My stuff here
}

void main(){
    //The session
    lt::session ses;
    //The data I want to insert into DHT
    std::string cadenaStr = "519d818411de49652b4aaf34850321de28bb2dce";        

    //Now I create the keys
    unsigned char seed[32];
    unsigned char public_key[32];
    unsigned char private_key[64];
    unsigned char signature[32];
    ed25519_create_seed(seed);
    ed25519_create_keypair(public_key, private_key, seed);
    ed25519_sign(signature, cadenaStr.c_str(), sizeof(cadenaStr.c_str()), public_key, private_key);

    //How can I use this?, where is the data supposed to go? :|
    ses.dht_put_item(public_key, cb, false);
}
```

On libtorrent/session_handler.hpp this method is defined as

```
void dht_put_item(boost::array<char, 32> key
    , boost::function<void(entry&, boost::array<char,64>&
    , boost::uint64_t&, std::string const&)> cb
    , std::string salt = std::string());
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the libtorrent repository that I use for testing. It can generate keys, put and get both mutable and immutable items.

https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/tools/dht_put.cpp

> How can I use this?, where is the data supposed to go? :|

You provide the data in the callback that's called. The reason for this kind of API is that there are use cases where you want to *mutate* the data, and then you need to first know whether something is already stored under this key, and what it is.

Comment: Thanks, the binding worked perfectly. I'm opening another question because I've got another problem and I think that other post will make the answer clearer for other users. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the settings pack for your session.

```
lt::settings_pack settings;
settings.set_bool(settings_pack::enable_dht, false);
settings.set_int(settings_pack::alert_mask, 0xffffffff);
ses.apply_settings(settings);
settings.set_bool(settings_pack::enable_dht, true);
ses.apply_settings(settings);
```

Then you need to wait until you receive a boostrap message by waiting for an alert.

```
wait_for_alert(ses, dht_bootstrap_alert::alert_type);
```

Last, your dht_put_item call:

```
char const* cadenaStr = "519d818411de49652b4aaf34850321de28bb2dce"; 
dht_put_item(public_key, std::bind(&put_string, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4, public_key, private_key, cadenaStr));
```

You will need these functions:

```
static alert* wait_for_alert(session* ses, int alert_type)
{
    alert* ret = nullptr;
    bool found = false;
    while (!found)
    {
        ses->wait_for_alert(seconds(5));
        std::vector<alert*> alerts;
        ses->pop_alerts(&alerts);
        for (std::vector<alert*>::iterator i = alerts.begin()
            , end(alerts.end()); i != end; ++i)
        {
            if ((*i)->type() != alert_type)
            {
                continue;
            }
            ret = *i;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

static void put_string(
    entry& e
    ,boost::array<char, 64>& sig
    ,boost::int64_t& seq
    ,std::string const& salt
    ,boost::array<char, 32> const& pk
    ,boost::array<char, 64> const& sk
    ,char const* str)
{
    using dht::sign_mutable_item;
    if (str != NULL) {
        e = std::string(str);
        std::vector<char> buf;
        bencode(std::back_inserter(buf), e);
        dht::signature sign;
        seq++;
        sign = sign_mutable_item(buf, salt, dht::sequence_number(seq)
            , dht::public_key(pk.data())
            , dht::secret_key(sk.data()));
        sig = sign.bytes;
    }
}
```